# How does std::async "store" an arbitrary exception?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, asynchronous, future

I am not able to understand how is it possible for `std::async` to store any exception, not just something derived from `std::exception`. I played around with the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

void f()
{
    std::cout << "\t\tIn f() we throw an exception" << std::endl;
    throw 1; // throw an int
}

int main()
{
    std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, f);
    std::cout << "Main thread sleeping 1s..." << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); // sleep one second
    std::cout << "Main thread waking up" << std::endl;
    try
    {
        fut.get();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "We caught an exception!" << std::endl;
        throw; // rethrow
    }
}
```

I launch `f()` asynchronously, then throw an `int` inside `f`. Magically, this `int` is caught and stored by the future returned by `std::async`. I understand that is possible to `catch(...)` the exception in `std::async`, but how can the latter store it without knowing the exception type? The exception is not derived from some base class (in this case one perhaps can "clone" it via some `Base::clone`), but can be any exception. Can we somehow magically "deduce" the exception type?

To summarize, my question is:

How can we store an arbitrary exception inside an object then re-throw it at some later time, without knowing the exception type?

Comment: [exception_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr)

Comment: @BryanChen thanks, didn't know about this, but I guess the question still remains, how can the `exception_ptr` deduce the type via `std::current_exception()`? It seems that `std::current_exception` is responsible with "capturing" the exception.

Comment: Wouldn't it just store it as a [std::type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)?

Comment: @Xiao the exception is thrown at runtime, and that's essentially my question, how is the type "captured"? It looks like internally something similar to template/auto type deduction takes place.

Comment: So you're asking about the implementation details of [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)?

Comment: @Xiao, I can imagine how `typeid` works. I don't understand how one applies `typeid` to an object of unknown type at compile time. The exception is thrown at runtime, how can `std::current_exception()` deduce its type? It's not like having something like `catch(Exception& e) { std::cout<<typeid(e).name()}`, because the exception is generic, not necessarily of type `Exception`.

Comment: Oh right. It might help to know that for every exception, the symbol that holds the exception type needs to be publically available at runtime. This can be a problem when a shared library tries to hide all of its symbols, but then throws an exception of a hidden type. Bad things happen. Do a find for 'exception' on https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71536/discussion-between-xiao-and-vsoftco).

Comment: Extra info:  `std::exception_ptr` can not be implemented in portable C++.  It must be implemented in the "runtime library" which also implements exception throwing & catching, and the compiler will create calls into this library (so the compiler and runtime library must agree on a private API).

Comment: @HowardHinnant ahh ok, I was trying myself to come up with some toy model of "capturing" an exception and was failing miserably. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::async` could be implemented on top of `std::thread` and `std::packaged_task`.

`std::packaged_task` could be implemented (partly) on top of `std::exception_ptr` and related function (except that thread-exit ready function).

`std::exception_ptr` and related functions cannot be written in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I now realized that some parts of the library just cannot be written in the language itself ;)

Comment: They can be written in C++ (and are), just not portably.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this exactly answers your question, but this example might be helpful.

I compiled the following:

```
int main()
{
    throw 1;
}
```

with the command

```
g++ -fdump-tree-gimple -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

The [gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) (gcc's intermediate output) is:

```
int main() ()
{
  void * D.1970;
  int D.1974;

  D.1970 = __cxa_allocate_exception (4);
  try
    {
      MEM[(int *)D.1970] = 1;
    }
  catch
    {
      __cxa_free_exception (D.1970);
    }
  __cxa_throw (D.1970, &_ZTIi, 0B);
  D.1974 = 0;
  return D.1974;
}
```

So it calls `__cxa_throw` with the address of the a symbol that represents a type. In this case the type is `_ZTIi`, which is the [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) type of an integer.

**Types not available at compile time**

The type symbols only need to be available at run time. In a dynamic library that is trying to hide as many symbols as it can, it needs to make sure that any exceptions that aren't caught and dealt with internally are available. For more info, see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility, particularly the section `Problems with C++ exceptions (please read!)`.

It would be interesting to see how this worked between dynamic libraries compiled with different compilers that had different naming schemes.

Comment: It doesn't work with different compilers unless they purposefully use the same ABI, including mangling.  And that's generally true of any C++ feature.  One compiler can't even call a C++-mangled function written by another compiler unless the two agree on mangling.  Here is one popular ABI specification: http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/

Comment: @Xiao, thanks, I thought that the mechanism can be implemented purely in C++ (and not by the runtime library)