# Is everything in C++11 STL user-implementable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that libs like `<map>`, `<vector>` and `<algorithm>` can be implemented by user even if they do not exist in the standard libraries.

But is some of the classes or functions in C++11 STL just "compiler-magic" that cannot be implemented manually?

---

**EDIT**
By STL, I meant the *standard template libraries*, which do not requires extra linking.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the library code of any major all purpose language can be (and probably has been) written in that language.

Comment: Please don't say STL if you mean C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I meant the standard template libraries, not including libs that are requires extra linking, such as the POSIX ones.

Comment: @RnMss, that doesn't clarify anything at all. Are you including `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, `std::locale`, `std::system_error`, `std::typeindex`? They aren't templates.

Comment: @RnMss The "Standard Template Library" was one set of template classes & interfaces; parts of it were adapted and adopted as the "C++ standard library," which also contains lots of stuff not part of the STL. [Further reading](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/).

Comment: @Angew, the last sentence isn't true, using `std::thread` typically requires linking to `libpthread` on POSIX platforms.

Comment: @JonathanWakely OK, removed.

Comment: You probably want someone like Howard Hinnant to weigh in on this, but from what I've seen of clang's libc++, there are calls to internals in the `_VSTD` namespace. It's hard to see how `<atomic>` could be implemented with pure C++11.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Quite possibly, but not all library code can be implemented *portably* in the language. For example, you can't implement I/O routines without some underlying system-specific support (unless you implement a file system in memory).

Comment: The Standard Template Libraries do require extra linking- apart from anything else, all major compilers currently implement EH routines in external libraries that are linked in.

Comment: @BrettHale: It probably depends on whether or not you consider using C11's atomics is cheating.

Comment: The term "C++11 STL" is strange. It doesn't really appear in the standard, for instance.   The answer for your original question using "C++11 STL" would be "Yes. it is all implementable", it seems.    In any case, the same question applied to the "C++11 standard library"  seems like a more interesting question. I'd suggest changing your question  to that, both because it is more interesting and  because there are good answers for that question already written below.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Even something as simple as `offsetof` from the C standard library requires "cheating" as it cannot be implemented in a strictly conforming way. ;-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you mean the part of the standard library that originated from Alexander Stepanov's *Standard Template Library*, then you can implement all of it without any compiler "magic" (i.e., you only need normal functionality that's required by the rest of the C++ standard).

Algorithms operate on iterators. The operations they need from the iterator are defined by the class of iterator on which they operate (see below). The algorithm simply carries out normal operations such as assigning to elements and swapping elements.

All iterators provide a few operations such as increment and dereference. Bidirectional iterators also provide decrement, and random access iterators provide addition/subtraction. None of these is particularly complex it implement using standard compiler features.

Containers are similar to algorithms in that they mostly operate on data via iterators. They also use allocator classes to allocate memory, create objects in that memory, and so on. Although writing an allocator used to be fairly complex (and the requirements poorly documented) C++11 has simplified the task considerably (and it never required anything non-standard).

If you take "STL" to mean the STandard Library in general, then yes, there are quite a few parts that require some compiler magic of various sorts.

Some of these are defined in terms of lower-level components, so (for example) iostreams are defined in terms of C's getchar/puthchar<sup>1</sup> to get data from/to the outside world. Other parts (e.g., type traits, std::uncaught_exception) provide an interface to data that's generated by the compiler, but isn't available to portable code by other means.

---

<sup>1.  Note, however, that even though iostreams are defined in terms of reading and writing via C functions, they're not required to actually use those C functions, just to do the same things as if they had.</sup>

Comment: Your footnote, I think, refers just to the *standard* streams (`cin` and such), and when they are synchronized with `stdio` (which is the default). Without synchronization they can do their own thing; e.g. `cout` can be fully buffered even when `STDOUT` is line buffered.

Comment: @Hurkyl: No, I'm talking about iostreams in general. If you trace back through the standard far enough, you get to a point that the data that's written to the external stream is written as if it had been done by putchar. This is less about cout being fully buffered even though stdout may not be, and more about things like what the phrase "fully buffered" actually means.

Comment: I've seen that statement when tracing through the standard to see what `sync_with_stdio(true)` means, but I haven't seen it for general streams -- as I recall, all of general stuff talks about "controlled sequences" and stuff, without reference to `stdio` at all.

Comment: @Hurkyl: For the standard ones (e.g., cout) you get: "The header `<iostream>` declares objects that associate objects with the standard C streams provided for by the functions declared in <cstdio> (27.9.2) [...]". For file streams, you get things like: "The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an object of class basic_filebuf<charT, traits> are the same as for reading and writing with the Standard C library FILEs.", "If the open operation succeeds and (mode & ios_base::ate) != 0, positions the file to the end (as
if by calling std::fseek(file,0,SEEK_END)).", etc.

Comment: Does "Standard Template Library" include `<initializer_list>`, `<type_trait>` and  `<new>` ?

Comment: @RnMss: No. Alex Stepanov's library included containers, algorithms and iterators. It did originally include a string class, but only because his compiler didn't have a standard string at the time; it wasn't really intended to be part of the library.

Answer (score 18):

I'm assuming you mean the C++11 standard library, not the STL (which is a library of algorithms, iterators and containers from the 1990s).

The answer depends what you mean by "implemented manually". Do you mean in pure C++? i.e. no assembly code and no OS-specific features such as POSIX memory allocation functions, or even lower-level system calls to the kernel?

Because if you're prepared to write assembly and call directly into the kernel, you can implement nearly everything, but it's not very practical. Even writing your own `std::malloc()` or `operator new` is very hard without building it on top of something lower-level such as `sbrk()`. Without something like `malloc` it's hard to write `std::allocator` and so hard to implement `std::vector`!

`std::system_clock` also relies on facilities provided by the operating system, you either need a lower-level API such as POSIX's `clock_gettime()` or access to a hardware clock in the CPU. Even `std::time()` defined in `<ctime>` needs something like that.

So let's assume relying on the C library for features such as `malloc` is OK, but we want to avoid writing assembly and non-C++.

It is not possible to implement `std::atomic` efficiently in pure C++. You need some compiler magic or assembly code to provide the necessary synchronization guarantees. The libstdc++ implementation of `std::atomic` relies on GCC's [__atomic built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) which are "compiler magic". The libc++ implementation of `std::atomic` makes use of the `_Atomic` keyword, which is defined by C11 and supported by `clang++` but is not defined in standard C++. In both cases the library implementation relies on non-standard features of the compiler to provide the platform-specific assembly necessary to provide the required behaviour.

Alternatively, you could just implement `std::atomic` inefficiently using a mutex, but that just shifts the requirement for "magical" synchronization properties onto the mutex type. At the very least, an implementation needs to provide `std::atomic_flag` which can't be done in pure C++. Without `std::atomic_flag` the other atomic types and `std::mutex` cannot be implemented in pure C++, so require either platform-specific assembly code, or require using a lower-level library such as Pthreads which provides the necessary primitives (which themselves will either be implemented in assembly or with non-portable compiler magic).

As pointed out at [How does std::async "store" an arbitrary exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685117/how-does-stdasync-store-an-arbitrary-exception#comment45664112_28685117) there are parts of the C++ runtime such as `std::typeinfo` and `std::exception_ptr` which can be written in C++, but not portably. The runtime has to define the data structures and internal details of RTTI and exception handling, and provide entry points that the compiler will call so that e.g. `throw` in your C++ code calls the relevant routine from the runtime to allocate an exception object. So you could implement those things yourself, but unless you conform to the right API the compiler won't use them so they won't work!

But even if you're prepared to write assembly and call directly into the kernel, several type traits rely on compiler magic and cannot be implemented by the user, for example `is_standard_layout`, `is_trivial`, `is_trivially_constructible` and the other `is_trivially_xxx` traits. These all depend on properties of a type which cannot be tested for in code, only the compiler can do the necessary inspection and tell you if a type has the property (and the same applies to the C++14 `is_final` trait).

Comment: "_Atomic is not part of C++" - That's somewhat odd. Yes, you have `std::atomic` so it'd be rather useless and a duplicate but completely excluding it?

Comment: @black: `_Atomic` was one of those C additions that happened relatively recently (in C11, apparently).  Each language did atomics their own way, as separate languages are wont to do.  C++ hasn't been overly concerned with copying every C feature for a while now.

Answer (score 11):

Not all of them are user-implementable. Some classes can only be implemented with compiler extensions.

GCC provides the "compiler-magic" for type traits.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Type-Traits.html#Type-Traits

GCC also provides atomic builtins,

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins

`initializer_list` is usually implemented on that compiler itself has access to the private function, which is in this case the constructor.

Comment: "`initializer_list` is _usually_ ..." - so does "usually" mean that `initializer_list` can be implemenet manually?

Comment: It can be written in pure C++ but it might not work. The compiler relies on non-standard, non-portable features of initializer_list so however you implement it you must ensure you meet whatever your compiler expects, which might not work with a different compiler

Answer (score -8):

The [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator which depends on the [`<typeinfo>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo) header is one example.

The other case is the [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), which is basically a [library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/initializer_list) add-on with special core language privileges. It is for example considered in variable initialization rules.

I guess there are more things that are both add-on libraries and base language constructs, but those are the ones I can remember for now.

Comment: But it is true after all - doesn't it?